# Learning scripting/programming (beginning)

Tags: bash, shell

What I am asking can be a bit silly and weird by anyway, I decided to ask you.

I am working as network security administrator and have knowledge and experience on cyber security as well. 2 month ago I Started my master degree on Cyber Security and now really want to continue my career on Cyber. Along with network and cyber skills I though having some programming languages in pocket will really benefit me. Shell scripting and Python are the only ones which really catch my interest.

I started with bash scripting and just wrote couple of little scripts. I wonder do you know any source which can I use for exercising. I am usually used to learn when I am actually searching and doing something. Therefore if for instance there is any page where I can find tasks for bash scripts with what I can practice and try do find solution, myself.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you only interested in these two languages? There are many interesting languages out.

Comment: Start following the [tag:bash] tag, pick a nice question and try to answer it. If you can't, most likely a solution will be posted. If you can, we'll give you points.

Comment: Kindly follow this link for more information about the cyber security jobs and roles in industry after enrolling to this course.http://www.career.alnafi.com/cat#a_aid=101&a_bid=d6f11fdd

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can direct yourself to :

https://cmdchallenge.com/

https://www.codewars.com/

Both sites are awesome and contain many challenges that will really help you to learn how to code and script.

Comment: Please don't answer blatantly off-topic questions.